# Testing remove_cap, remove_menu_page : still working even if I comment or remove the code

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin, customization

I work on wordpress.
I have tested "remove_cap" functions to see what it did.

```
function modif_cap_client() {
$role=get_role('editor');
$role->remove_cap('edit_pages');    
}
```

Then, I have tested the "remove_menu_page" function so that the "page" item isn't accessible for a user in the administration. I did this in the functions.php of the front office theme (maybe it's wrong)

```
function remove_menu_items() {
    remove_menu_page('index.php');
    remove_menu_page('separator1'); 
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items');
```

It worked. Then I commented this code, removed it from the functions.php file but there is nothing to do : the page item isn't displayed anymore. When I want to click on the page link (from the homepage of the administration), it mentions "you don't have persmission to add contents" although I am under administrator profile.

I don't know what to do to resolve that problem. Maybe these functions change something in the database but what ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add or remove a user role's capability, then it will be in effect until gets revoked explicitly again (so it will not be revoked even if you comment or remove). Try revoke (add) the capability again which will resolve your issue.

```
function modify_cap_client() {
    $role = get_role('editor');
    $role->add_cap('edit_pages');    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'modify_cap_client');
```

You can then comment or remove after first run. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved. If I get it right, the remove_cap method changes datas in the db.  It worked